# Single Button with Drop Down Menu Effects - Help Refine

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a client site and they wish to have a drop down button on the main banner of the site.

I was able to code it and get it to work but it seems to be a bit temperamental. The button works, but not every time you click it and certainly not smoothly. Can someone look at this and let me know if their is something else conflicting with this code or what I might be able to do to fine tune it and get it to work better?

I'm using the following CSS:

```
  /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: rgba(102, 146, 255, 0.87);
    color: white;
    padding: 9px 15px 14px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #6692FF;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 9px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4A5056;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f9f9f9}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

The Following HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><span style="     vertical-align: bottom;font-size: 24px; ">LISTEN</span> <i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-4x"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
 <a href="http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/financialexchange/listen-live/" class="popup" data-height="300" data-width="300" data-scrollbars="0" alt="LISTEN LIVE">
LISTEN LIVE</a>
    <a href="http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/financialexchange/on-demand/">ON DEMAND</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following JS:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The link is http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/financialexchange/ is the blue Listen button in the top right hand corner in the banner.

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I've noticed something about it. At the first look it appears that it works only sometimes but it actually works fine. Only the "wrapping" area (the outside one) is working. If you press the text or the volume picture it won't. This is just a remark.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you are saying. I'll look at that, and hopefully someone else will chime in.

Comment: Do you accept jQuery? It would be much simplier with it. I'm writing the code for jQuery..if you want.

Comment: Sure I'll try that if you take the time to do so. I am able to get it to work a lot better now just based off of your previous remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok You can do is remove span inside the button and paste span styling in button class like this

CSS

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: rgba(102, 146, 255, 0.87);
    color: white;
    padding: 9px 15px 14px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 6px;

vertical-align: bottom;font-size: 24px; /*HERE The CODE of SPAN*/

}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #6692FF;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 9px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4A5056;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f9f9f9}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">LISTEN <i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-4x"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
 <a href="http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/financialexchange/listen-live/" class="popup" data-height="300" data-width="300" data-scrollbars="0" alt="LISTEN LIVE">
LISTEN LIVE</a>
    <a href="http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/financialexchange/on-demand/">ON DEMAND</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you! Also how can I removed the outter highlight that appears around the button after it's selected?

Comment: @kgmack You can remove by adding "   outline:none;   "  into .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {

Answer (score 0):

You set the function 'myFunction' **only** for the button but that doesn't mean it will be triggered by the **span** or **i** elements inside your button.

To solve it try this(with jQuery):
   
**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropbtn"> <!--CHANGED THIS-->
           <span style="vertical-align: bottom;font-size: 24px; ">LISTEN</span> 
           <i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/financialexchange/listen-live/" class="popup" data-height="300" data-width="300" data-scrollbars="0" alt="LISTEN LIVE">LISTEN LIVE</a>
          <a href="http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/financialexchange/on-demand/">ON DEMAND</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

**JS/JQ**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".dropbtn").click(function(){
           document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    });


    $("body").click(function(e){
        if(e.target.className !== "form_wrapper"){
           var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
           var i;
           for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                     openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
           }
        }
    });
});
```